# How to use inner join in given query and optimize it?

Tags: sql, optimization

I have queries like below and I want to optimise them.

```
car_wheels AS (
    SELECT wheel FROM devices WHERE type = '4x4'
),
white_wheels AS (
    SELECT wheel FROM devices WHERE color = 'white'
),
car_white_wheels AS (
    SELECT * FROM car_wheels INTERSECT SELECT * FROM white_wheels
)

SELECT wheel FROM devices JOIN users ON devices.user_id = user.id WHERE wheel IN (SELECT wheel FROM car_white_wheels) AND users.organization_id = 999;
```

I have an idea to use inner join here. Is this correct? What else can I optimize here easily?

I want to find white car_wheels for given user.organization_id.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tag.  Sample data and desired results would clarify your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just doing this?

```
select wheel
from devices d join
     users u
     on d.user_id = u.id
where (type = '4x4' and color = 'white') and
      u.organization_id = 999;
```

Am I missing something?

Or, if `wheel` could have features on multiple rows:

```
select wheel
from devices d join
     users u
     on d.user_id = u.id
where (type = '4x4' or color = 'white') and
      u.organization_id = 999
group by wheel
having sum(case when type = '4x4' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when color = 'white' then 1 else 0 end) > 0';
```

Comment: @regedarek . . . I missed that because that information is only in the query far to the right.